# Sharing a iPhoto Library between users on the same computer

Tags: photos.app, sharing, user-account

I tried to share my iPhoto library with putting it into my sharing folder. I changed the permissions, so the other users can use it. Now they can use it, but if they add new photos, i cannot edit them. They were displayed, but if I try to edit the, there is only a black screen instead of the picture.

Comment: If Patrix's answer doesn't work, please edit your question so that you list the specific step you are having problems with in the Apple guide on how to do what you ask. Can we assume the library still works for your main user?

Answer (score 3):

Did you have a look at what [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1198) proposes in the corresponding support document?

It covers using an external hard drive to house one iPhoto Library as well as moving those files to the /Users/Shared folder on the Mac.