# Share Photos library with other user on same Mac

Tags: photos, sharing

I would like to share my Photos library with another account on the same Mac. I have done exactly what @metatechbe suggested in his answer to [How can I share Photos across multiple users on Apple Photos, without paying for iCloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192333/how-can-i-share-photos-across-multiple-users-on-apple-photos-without-paying-for).

A actually can access the Photo library from both accounts now. But after user1 has used it, user2 sees a `Repair Library Permissions` dialog:

```
This photo library is locked or you do not have permissions to make changes to it. Photos can try to repair the permissions.
```

Other posts like

- [Sharing a iPhoto Library between users on the same computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33227/sharing-a-iphoto-library-between-users-on-the-same-computer)
- [Sharing a Photos library across multiple accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225915/sharing-a-photos-library-across-multiple-accounts)

aimed in the same direction, but no solution was found.

Is there a way to seamlessly make the a Photos library usable by two users? Of course, one needs to quit Photos before the other open the library. But the permissions dialog should not appear all the time.

Comment: You can put your photo library into the shared folder? Will do the job pretty well, I think

Comment: I have done that, as was suggested in @metatechbe's reply to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192333/how-can-i-share-photos-across-multiple-users-on-apple-photos-without-paying-for. But this does not get rid of the `Repair Library Permissions` dialog.

Comment: only one person at a time can use the library. It is not designed to be shared between multiple users. The errors you are getting are likely a consequence of you using it in a way not envisioned (nor supported) by Apple